# move element right and left while scrolling issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, scroll

I'm trying to move an element to left and right while scrolling up and down in this example [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/x0vtopzv/) the problem is the div will keep moving to reach out of the page and doesn't return to its original position. This is the example I'm trying to simulate [Original Example](http://brunozampa.it/en/aurea)

HTML

```
<div class='container'>
<div class='inner'>
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
var st = $(this).scrollTop();
if (st > lastScrollTop){
    var offset = $(".inner").offset();
    var w = $(window);
    var x = offset.left;
    console.log(x);
    $(".inner").css("left",x+50);
} else {
    var offset = $(".inner").offset();
    var w = $(window);
    var y = offset.left;
    console.log(y);
    $(".inner").css("left",y-50);
}
lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

CSS

```
.container{width:100%; position: relative; float:left; background:#fff; height:1200px;}
.inner{width:150px; height:100px; position:absolute; top:20%; left:10%; background:red;}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to offset it by the scrolled amount, not move it by an amount each time. You are queuing up multiple moves and adding 50px each time.

```
var offset = $(".inner").offset();
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  $(".inner").css("left", st + offset.left);
});
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/x0vtopzv/1/

Once it is locked to the scrolling, you can adjust the position using a multiplier on the `st` value.

**Note:** JSFiddle has an 8px margin on the `body`. That throws out the offset position and needs to be removed or taken into account.

https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/x0vtopzv/6/

Comment: it works but it doesn't return to the original place see this https://jsfiddle.net/x0vtopzv/5/

Comment: That is probably down to the styling giving an incorrect left offset. Let me take a look :)

Comment: @PHPUser: Yep. JSFiddle has an 8px margin on the `body`. https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/x0vtopzv/6/ That throws out the offset position and needs to be removed or taken into account.

Comment: I have a page with bootstrap but has the same issue though body and html are 0 margin 0 padding is there any way to adjust this? I've changed var st = $(this).scrollTop() to var st = $(this).scrollTop()-50 and worked on large screen but on tablet and phone it's moved to the left

Comment: @PHPUser: I have seen code which walks the ancestors to calculate the correct offset of an element, but don't remember the details. Start Googling that issue? :)